# To find geometric probability

Tags: probability-theory

Two points are chosen at random on a line segment of length $9$ cm . The probability that the distance between these $2$ points is less than $3$ cm is?

As definition of geometric probability says that:
 P=desired area/total area

Equation of straight line is $y=x$

So $P(X<3) = \int_0^3 x\,dx$.
And divididing it by $9$ we get  $0.5$

Is that approach correct?

Comment: Consider plotting the location of the first point $x$ on a horizontal axis, and the location of the second point $y$ on a vertical axis. The distribution of all $(x,y)$ pairs you could get is uniformly distributed on a $9 \times 9$ square. You want to find the area of the part of the square where $|x-y| < 3$, which is a diagonal strip. Then divide this area by $9^2$ (the area of the square).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

Here is how to start the problem:

Let $X_1, X_2 \sim \operatorname{Uni}(0,9)$

$X_i$ takes value from $0$ to $9$, the total area would be $9^2$.

We have to find the area of the region that corresponds to $|X_1-X_2|<3$ then divide by the total area.

[image]

Comment: Is the graph makes two triangles

Comment: I have included the relevant figure, the red regionis the region of interest.

Comment: Got it.thanks for ur time....But ans. is still 0.5. Right?

Comment: how do you get $0.5$?

Comment: (81-36)/81........U told me to divide by 81

Comment: and you get $0.5$? Try to leave it in fractional form or take in more digit.

Comment: Yeah... Obviously

Answer (score 0):

On Careful Observation we can spot two parallelograms each of equal area and two triangles each of equal area which makes the calculation of shaded area a very easy task. The first parallelogram has coordinates at (0,0),(0,3),(6,9),(6,6) giving area = 3*6 = 18 units. Similarly another parallelogram with coordinates at (3,0), (3,3),(9,9),(9,6) has area of 3*6 (base* height) = 18. Now remaining two triangles have same dimensions base = 3 and height = 3 Area = 4.5 each. Summing to 18+18+9 = 45. Area calculation is easy the other way like demon mentioned.